# Подскажите пожалуйста на каком это языке, и где она смотрит историю USB

Tags: delphi

я чайник, причем полный с помощью программы Restorator просмотрел екзещник она мне выдала данные ниже строки. Мне необходимо узнать по каким путям она смотрит историю USB устройств. Спасибо за ответ

```
object FormScan: TFormScan
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'FUSB'
  ClientHeight = 566
  ClientWidth = 792
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCloseQuery = FormCloseQuery
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Image1: TImage
    Left = 0
    Top = 52
    Width = 792
    Height = 514
    Align = alClient
    Center = True
    Picture.Data = { Бинарные Данные (сохраните файл на диск, чтобы увидеть это) }
    ExplicitLeft = 140
    ExplicitTop = 104
    ExplicitWidth = 652
    ExplicitHeight = 432
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 52
    Width = 792
    Height = 514
    Align = alClient
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    Caption = 'Panel1'
    TabOrder = 0
    TabStop = True
    Visible = False
    object Splitter1: TSplitter
      Left = 217
      Top = 0
      Height = 514
      ExplicitLeft = 280
      ExplicitTop = 192
      ExplicitHeight = 100
    end
    object TV: TTreeView
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Width = 217
      Height = 514
      Align = alLeft
      HideSelection = False
      Indent = 19
      ReadOnly = True
      TabOrder = 0
      TabStop = False
      OnChange = TVChange
    end
    object PageControl: TPageControl
      Left = 220
      Top = 0
      Width = 572
      Height = 514
      ActivePage = TS_USB
      Align = alClient
      TabOrder = 1
      object TS_Date: TTabSheet
        Caption = 'Date'
        TabVisible = False
        object LV_Date: TListView
          Tag = 1
          Left = 0
          Top = 0
          Width = 564
          Height = 504
          Align = alClient
          Columns = <>
          LargeImages = Img_48x48
          TabOrder = 0
          OnDblClick = LV_DblClick
        end
      end
      object TS_System: TTabSheet
        Caption = 'System'
        ImageIndex = 1
        TabVisible = False
        object LV_Dir_System: TListView
          Tag = 2
          Left = 0
          Top = 0
          Width = 564
          Height = 504
          Align = alClient
          Columns = <>
          LargeImages = Img_48x48
          TabOrder = 0
          OnDblClick = LV_DblClick
        end
      end
      object TS_All: TTabSheet
        Caption = 'All'
        ImageIndex = 2
        TabVisible = False
        object LV_System: TListView
          Tag = 2
          Left = 0
          Top = 0
          Width = 564
          Height = 504
          Align = alClient
          Columns = <
            item
              AutoSize = True
            end>
          Groups = <
            item
              Header = 'zxczxc'
              GroupID = 0
              State = [lgsNormal, lgsCollapsible]
              HeaderAlign = taLeftJustify
              FooterAlign = taLeftJustify
              TopDescription = 'vbcvbcbv'
              TitleImage = -1
              ExtendedImage = -1
            end
            item
              Header = 'asdasda'
              GroupID = 1
              State = [lgsNormal]
              HeaderAlign = taLeftJustify
              FooterAlign = taLeftJustify
              TitleImage = -1
              ExtendedImage = -1
            end
            item
              Header = 'Имя компьютера'
              GroupID = 2
              State = [lgsNormal]
              HeaderAlign = taLeftJustify
              FooterAlign = taLeftJustify
              TitleImage = -1
              ExtendedImage = -1
            end
            item
              Header = 'Имя пользователя'
              GroupID = 3
              State = [lgsNormal]
              HeaderAlign = taLeftJustify
              FooterAlign = taLeftJustify
              TitleImage = -1
              ExtendedImage = -1
            end
            item
              Header = 'Дирректория Windows'
              GroupID = 5
              State = [lgsNormal]
              HeaderAlign = taLeftJustify
              FooterAlign = taLeftJustify
              TitleImage = -1
              ExtendedImage = -1
            end
            item
              Header = 'Системная дирректория'
              GroupID = 4
              State = [lgsNormal]
              HeaderAlign = taLeftJustify
              FooterAlign = taLeftJustify
              TitleImage = -1
              ExtendedImage = -1
            end
            item
              Header = 'Переменная OS'
              GroupID = 7
              State = [lgsNormal]
              HeaderAlign = taLeftJustify
              FooterAlign = taLeftJustify
              TitleImage = -1
              ExtendedImage = -1
            end
            item
              Header = 'Переменная PATH'
              GroupID = 6
              State = [lgsNormal]
              HeaderAlign = taLeftJustify
              FooterAlign = taLeftJustify
              TitleImage = -1
              ExtendedImage = -1
            end
            item
              Header = 'Переменная TMP'
              GroupID = 8
              State = [lgsNormal]
              HeaderAlign = taLeftJustify
              FooterAlign = taLeftJustify
              TitleImage = -1
              ExtendedImage = -1
            end>
          LargeImages = Img_48x48
          GroupView = True
          ReadOnly = True
          RowSelect = True
          ShowColumnHeaders = False
          TabOrder = 0
          ViewStyle = vsReport
          OnDblClick = LV_DblClick
        end
      end
      object TS_Autorun: TTabSheet
        Caption = 'Autorun'
        ImageIndex = 3
        TabVisible = False
        object LV_Autorun: TListView
          Left = 0
          Top = 0
          Width = 564
          Height = 504
          Align = alClient
          Columns = <
            item
              Caption = 'Элемент загрузки'
              Width = 200
            end
            item
              AutoSize = True
              Caption = 'Команда/Путь'
            end
            item
              Caption = 'Ключ'
              Width = 80
            end>
          ColumnClick = False
          DoubleBuffered = True
          Groups = <
            item
              Header = 'HKLM'
              GroupID = 0
              State = [lgsNormal]
              HeaderAlign = taLeftJustify
              FooterAlign = taLeftJustify
              TitleImage = -1
              ExtendedImage = -1
            end
            item
              Header = 'HKCU'
              GroupID = 1
              State = [lgsNormal]
              HeaderAlign = taLeftJustify
              FooterAlign = taLeftJustify
              TitleImage = -1
              ExtendedImage = -1
            end
            item
              Header = 'Statrup'
              GroupID = 2
              State = [lgsNormal]
              HeaderAlign = taLeftJustify
              FooterAlign = taLeftJustify
              TitleImage = -1
              ExtendedImage = -1
            end>
          HideSelection = False
          GroupView = True
          ReadOnly = True
          RowSelect = True
          ParentDoubleBuffered = False
          SortType = stData
          TabOrder = 0
          TabStop = False
          ViewStyle = vsReport
        end
      end
      object TS_Installed: TTabSheet
        Caption = 'Insatlled'
        ImageIndex = 4
        TabVisible = False
        object LV_Installed: TListView
          Left = 0
          Top = 0
          Width = 564
          Height = 442
          Align = alClient
          Columns = <
            item
              AutoSize = True
              Caption = 'Установленное приложение'
            end
            item
              Caption = 'Версия'
              Width = 100
            end
            item
              Caption = 'Дата'
              Width = 100
            end>
          ColumnClick = False
          DoubleBuffered = True
          HideSelection = False
          ReadOnly = True
          RowSelect = True
          ParentDoubleBuffered = False
          SmallImages = ImageList1
          TabOrder = 0
          TabStop = False
          ViewStyle = vsReport
          OnChange = LV_InstalledChange
        end
        object Panel2: TPanel
          Left = 0
          Top = 442
          Width = 564
          Height = 62
          Align = alBottom
          BevelOuter = bvNone
          TabOrder = 1
          DesignSize = (
            564
            62)
          object Image2: TImage
            Left = 2
            Top = 5
            Width = 48
            Height = 48
            AutoSize = True
            Picture.Data = { Бинарные Данные (сохраните файл на диск, чтобы увидеть это) }
            Transparent = True
          end
          object Lbl_Dst: TLabel
            Left = 161
            Top = 23
            Width = 400
            Height = 13
            Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight]
            AutoSize = False
            EllipsisPosition = epPathEllipsis
          end
          object Lbl_Src: TLabel
            Left = 161
            Top = 7
            Width = 400
            Height = 13
            Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight]
            AutoSize = False
            EllipsisPosition = epPathEllipsis
          end
          object Lbl_Publisher: TLabel
            Left = 162
            Top = 40
            Width = 399
            Height = 13
            Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight]
            AutoSize = False
            EllipsisPosition = epPathEllipsis
          end
          object StaticText1: TStaticText
            Left = 56
            Top = 23
            Width = 100
            Height = 17
            Caption = 'Путь установки:'
            Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
            Font.Color = clWindowText
            Font.Height = -11
            Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
            Font.Style = [fsBold]
            ParentFont = False
            TabOrder = 0
          end
          object StaticText2: TStaticText
            Left = 56
            Top = 6
            Width = 62
            Height = 17
            Caption = 'Источник:'
            Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
            Font.Color = clWindowText
            Font.Height = -11
            Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
            Font.Style = [fsBold]
            ParentFont = False
            TabOrder = 1
          end
          object StaticText4: TStaticText
            Left = 56
            Top = 40
            Width = 98
            Height = 17
            Caption = 'Производитель:'
            Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
            Font.Color = clWindowText
            Font.Height = -11
            Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
            Font.Style = [fsBold]
            ParentFont = False
            TabOrder = 2
          end
        end
      end
      object TS_Service: TTabSheet
        Caption = 'Service'
        ImageIndex = 5
        TabVisible = False
        object OL_Service: TAdvOutlookList
          Left = 0
          Top = 0
          Width = 564
          Height = 424
          Align = alClient
          Columns = <
            item
              Caption = 'Group Column'
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end
            item
              Caption = 'Служба/Драйвер'
              Width = 300
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = [fsBold]
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end
            item
              Caption = 'column 2'
              Width = 200
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end
            item
              Caption = 'Путь запуска'
              Width = 100
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end>
          Color = clWhite
          DragDropSetting = ddDisabled
          GroupItemHeight = 34
          GroupShowCount = True
          HideSelection = True
          ItemHeight = 15
          LookUp.Method = lmDirect
          GroupColumnDisplay = gdHidden
          PreviewSettings.Column = 2
          PreviewSettings.Height = 15
          PreviewSettings.Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          PreviewSettings.Font.Color = clBlue
          PreviewSettings.Font.Height = -11
          PreviewSettings.Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
          PreviewSettings.Font.Style = []
          SelectionColor = clInfoBk
          SelectionTextColor = clRed
          SelectionOptions = []
          GroupFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          GroupFont.Color = 12150839
          GroupFont.Height = -11
          GroupFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
          GroupFont.Style = [fsBold]
          GroupCountFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          GroupCountFont.Color = clBlack
          GroupCountFont.Height = -11
          GroupCountFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
          GroupCountFont.Style = []
          ShowHint = True
          ShowNodes = True
          SortSettings.Enabled = False
          SortSettings.SortGroups = False
          TabOrder = 0
          URLSettings.FontStyle = [fsUnderline]
          Version = '1.7.1.0'
        end
        object Panel3: TPanel
          Left = 0
          Top = 424
          Width = 564
          Height = 80
          Align = alBottom
          BevelOuter = bvNone
          Caption = 'Panel3'
          TabOrder = 1
          Visible = False
        end
      end
      object TS_USB: TTabSheet
        Caption = 'TS_USB'
        ImageIndex = 8
        TabVisible = False
        object OL_USB: TAdvOutlookList
          Left = 0
          Top = 0
          Width = 564
          Height = 504
          Margins.Bottom = 30
          Align = alClient
          Columns = <
            item
              Caption = 'Group Column'
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
              Visible = False
            end
            item
              Caption = 'Продукт'
              Width = 300
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = [fsBold]
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end
            item
              Caption = 'Vid-Pid'
              Width = 100
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              Alignment = taCenter
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end
            item
              Caption = 'Серийный номер'
              Width = 200
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end
            item
              Caption = 'Первый запуск'
              Width = 120
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end
            item
              Caption = 'Последний запуск'
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end>
          Color = clWhite
          DragDropSetting = ddDisabled
          GroupItemHeight = 34
          GroupShowCount = True
          HideSelection = True
          LookUp.Method = lmDirect
          GroupColumnDisplay = gdHidden
          PreviewSettings.Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          PreviewSettings.Font.Color = clBlue
          PreviewSettings.Font.Height = -11
          PreviewSettings.Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
          PreviewSettings.Font.Style = []
          SelectionOptions = [soRightClickSelect]
          GroupFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          GroupFont.Color = 12150839
          GroupFont.Height = -11
          GroupFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
          GroupFont.Style = [fsBold]
          GroupCountFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          GroupCountFont.Color = clBlack
          GroupCountFont.Height = -11
          GroupCountFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
          GroupCountFont.Style = [fsBold]
          ShowHint = True
          ShowNodes = True
          SortSettings.SortGroups = False
          TabOrder = 0
          URLSettings.FontStyle = [fsUnderline]
          Version = '1.7.1.0'
        end
      end
      object TS_USBSTOR: TTabSheet
        Caption = 'USBSTOR'
        ImageIndex = 7
        TabVisible = False
        object OL_USBSTOR: TAdvOutlookList
          Left = 0
          Top = 0
          Width = 564
          Height = 504
          Margins.Bottom = 30
          Align = alClient
          Columns = <
            item
              Caption = 'Group Column'
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
              Visible = False
            end
            item
              Width = 20
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              ColumnType = ctImage
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
              HeaderImageIndex = 5
              HeaderHint = 'Регистрация'
              HeaderShowHint = True
            end
            item
              Width = 20
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              ColumnType = ctImage
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
              HeaderImageIndex = 6
              HeaderHint = 'Тип носителя'
              HeaderShowHint = True
            end
            item
              Caption = 'Продукт'
              Width = 120
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = [fsBold]
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end
            item
              Caption = 'Vid-Pid'
              Width = 60
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              Alignment = taCenter
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end
            item
              Caption = 'Серийный номер'
              Width = 200
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end
            item
              Caption = 'Первый запуск'
              Width = 120
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end
            item
              Caption = 'Последний запуск'
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end>
          Color = clWhite
          DragDropSetting = ddDisabled
          GroupItemHeight = 34
          GroupShowCount = True
          HideSelection = True
          LookUp.Method = lmDirect
          GroupColumnDisplay = gdHidden
          PreviewSettings.Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          PreviewSettings.Font.Color = clBlue
          PreviewSettings.Font.Height = -11
          PreviewSettings.Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
          PreviewSettings.Font.Style = []
          SelectionOptions = [soRightClickSelect]
          GroupFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          GroupFont.Color = 12150839
          GroupFont.Height = -11
          GroupFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
          GroupFont.Style = [fsBold]
          GroupCountFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          GroupCountFont.Color = clBlack
          GroupCountFont.Height = -11
          GroupCountFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
          GroupCountFont.Style = []
          ShowHint = True
          ShowNodes = True
          SortSettings.SortGroups = False
          TabOrder = 0
          URLSettings.FontStyle = [fsUnderline]
          Version = '1.7.1.0'
          OnItemRightClick = OL_USBSTORItemRightClick
        end
      end
      object TabSheet7: TTabSheet
        Caption = 'TabSheet7'
        ImageIndex = 6
        TabVisible = False
        object USB_Stat: TMemo
          Left = 0
          Top = 0
          Width = 564
          Height = 504
          Align = alClient
          Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          Font.Color = clWindowText
          Font.Height = -21
          Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
          Font.Style = []
          Lines.Strings = (
            'В разработке')
          ParentFont = False
          ScrollBars = ssVertical
          TabOrder = 0
        end
      end
      object TS_DevClass: TTabSheet
        Caption = 'TS_DevClass'
        ImageIndex = 9
        TabVisible = False
        object OL_DevClass: TAdvOutlookList
          Left = 0
          Top = 0
          Width = 564
          Height = 504
          Align = alClient
          Columns = <
            item
              Caption = 'Group Column'
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end
            item
              Caption = 'Num'
              Width = 150
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end
            item
              Caption = 'Vendor'
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end
            item
              Caption = 'Product'
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end
            item
              Caption = 'Revision'
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end
            item
              Caption = 'Serial'
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end>
          Color = clWhite
          GroupItemHeight = 34
          GroupShowCount = True
          HideSelection = True
          LookUp.Method = lmDirect
          GroupColumnDisplay = gdHidden
          PreviewSettings.Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          PreviewSettings.Font.Color = clBlue
          PreviewSettings.Font.Height = -11
          PreviewSettings.Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
          PreviewSettings.Font.Style = []
          GroupFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          GroupFont.Color = 12150839
          GroupFont.Height = -11
          GroupFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
          GroupFont.Style = [fsBold]
          GroupCountFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          GroupCountFont.Color = clBlack
          GroupCountFont.Height = -11
          GroupCountFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
          GroupCountFont.Style = []
          ShowHint = True
          ShowNodes = True
          SortSettings.SortGroups = False
          TabOrder = 0
          URLSettings.FontStyle = [fsUnderline]
          Version = '1.7.1.0'
        end
      end
      object TS_StorageRM: TTabSheet
        Caption = 'TS_StorageRM'
        ImageIndex = 10
        TabVisible = False
        object OL_StorageRM: TAdvOutlookList
          Left = 0
          Top = 0
          Width = 559
          Height = 489
          Columns = <
            item
              Caption = 'Group Column'
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end
            item
              Caption = 'Num'
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end
            item
              Caption = 'ParentIdPrefix'
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clWindowText
              Font.Height = -11
              Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
              Font.Style = []
              HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
              HeaderFont.Height = -11
              HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
              HeaderFont.Style = []
            end>
          Color = clWhite
          GroupItemHeight = 34
          GroupShowCount = True
          HideSelection = True
          LookUp.Method = lmDirect
          GroupColumnDisplay = gdHidden
          PreviewSettings.Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          PreviewSettings.Font.Color = clBlue
          PreviewSettings.Font.Height = -11
          PreviewSettings.Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
          PreviewSettings.Font.Style = []
          GroupFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          GroupFont.Color = 12150839
          GroupFont.Height = -11
          GroupFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
          GroupFont.Style = [fsBold]
          GroupCountFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          GroupCountFont.Color = clBlack
          GroupCountFont.Height = -11
          GroupCountFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
          GroupCountFont.Style = []
          ShowHint = True
          ShowNodes = True
          SortSettings.SortGroups = False
          TabOrder = 0
          URLSettings.FontStyle = [fsUnderline]
          Version = '1.7.1.0'
        end
      end
    end
  end
  object ToolBar2: TToolBar
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 792
    Height = 52
    AutoSize = True
    ButtonHeight = 52
    ButtonWidth = 74
    Caption = 'ToolBar1'
    Images = Img_32x32
    ShowCaptions = True
    TabOrder = 1
    object ToolButton8: TToolButton
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Action = A_Menu_Scan
    end
    object ToolButton9: TToolButton
      Left = 74
      Top = 0
      Width = 8
      Caption = 'ToolButton2'
      ImageIndex = 1
      Style = tbsSeparator
    end
    object ToolButton10: TToolButton
      Tag = 1
      Left = 82
      Top = 0
      Action = A_Menu_Open
    end
    object ToolButton11: TToolButton
      Tag = 2
      Left = 156
      Top = 0
      Action = A_Menu_Save
    end
    object ToolButton12: TToolButton
      Left = 230
      Top = 0
      Width = 8
      Caption = 'ToolButton5'
      ImageIndex = 3
      Style = tbsSeparator
    end
    object ToolButton13: TToolButton
      Tag = 3
      Left = 238
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'Назад'
      Enabled = False
      ImageIndex = 3
    end
    object ToolButton14: TToolButton
      Tag = 4
      Left = 312
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'Вперед'
      Enabled = False
      ImageIndex = 4
    end
    object ToolButton15: TToolButton
      Tag = 5
      Left = 386
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'Вверх'
      Enabled = False
      ImageIndex = 5
    end
    object ToolButton16: TToolButton
      Left = 460
      Top = 0
      Width = 8
      Caption = 'ToolButton9'
      ImageIndex = 6
      Style = tbsSeparator
    end
    object ToolButton17: TToolButton
      Tag = 6
      Left = 468
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'Отчет'
      Enabled = False
      ImageIndex = 6
      Visible = False
    end
    object ToolButton19: TToolButton
      Tag = 7
      Left = 542
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'ToolButton12'
      Enabled = False
      ImageIndex = 7
      Visible = False
    end
    object ToolButton18: TToolButton
      Left = 616
      Top = 0
      Width = 8
      Caption = 'ToolButton11'
      ImageIndex = 7
      Style = tbsSeparator
    end
    object ToolButton20: TToolButton
      Tag = 8
      Left = 624
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'О программе'
      Enabled = False
      ImageIndex = 8
      Visible = False
    end
  end
  object ActionList1: TActionList
    Images = Img_32x32
    Left = 424
    object A_Paint_All: TAction
      Category = 'Paint'
      Caption = 'A_Paint_All'
      OnExecute = Paint_All
    end
    object A_Paint_Node: TAction
      Category = 'Paint'
      Caption = 'A_Paint_Node'
      OnExecute = Paint_Node
    end
    object A_Menu_Scan: TAction
      Category = 'Menu'
      Caption = 'Сканировать'
      ImageIndex = 0
      OnExecute = Menu_Scan
    end
    object A_Menu_Open: TAction
      Category = 'Menu'
      Caption = 'Открыть'
      ImageIndex = 1
      OnExecute = Menu_Open
    end
    object A_Scan_Installed: TAction
      Category = 'Scan'
      Caption = 'A_Scan_Installed'
      OnExecute = Scan_Installed
    end
    object A_Mem_New: TAction
      Category = 'Memory'
      OnExecute = Mem_New
    end
    object A_Mem_Free: TAction
      Category = 'Memory'
      Caption = 'A_Mem_Free'
      OnExecute = Mem_Free
    end
    object A_Paint_Installed: TAction
      Category = 'Paint'
      Caption = 'A_Paint_Installed'
      OnExecute = Paint_Installed
    end
    object A_Scan_Class: TAction
      Category = 'Scan'
      Caption = 'A_Scan_Class'
      OnExecute = Scan_Class
    end
    object A_Scan_System: TAction
      Category = 'Scan'
      Caption = 'A_Scan_System'
      OnExecute = A_Scan_SystemExecute
    end
    object A_Paint_System: TAction
      Category = 'Paint'
      Caption = 'A_Paint_System'
      OnExecute = Paint_System
    end
    object A_Scan_Autorun: TAction
      Category = 'Scan'
      Caption = 'A_Scan_Autorun'
      OnExecute = Scan_Autorun
    end
    object A_Paint_Autorun: TAction
      Category = 'Paint'
      Caption = 'A_Paint_Autorun'
      OnExecute = Paint_Autorun
    end
    object A_Scan_Service: TAction
      Category = 'Scan'
      Caption = 'A_Scan_Service'
      OnExecute = Scan_Service
    end
    object A_Scan_Wow64: TAction
      Category = 'Scan'
      Caption = 'A_Scan_Wow64'
      OnExecute = Scan_Wow64
    end
    object A_Paint_Service: TAction
      Category = 'Paint'
      Caption = 'A_Paint_Service'
      OnExecute = Paint_Service
    end
    object A_Scan_USBSTOR: TAction
      Category = 'Scan'
      Caption = 'A_Scan_USBSTOR'
      OnExecute = Scan_USBSTOR
    end
    object A_Paint_USBSTOR: TAction
      Category = 'Paint'
      Caption = 'A_Paint_USBSTOR'
      OnExecute = Paint_USBSTOR
    end
    object A_Scan_USB: TAction
      Category = 'Scan'
      Caption = 'A_Scan_USB'
      OnExecute = Scan_USB
    end
    object A_Paint_USB: TAction
      Category = 'Paint'
      Caption = 'A_Paint_USB'
      OnExecute = Paint_USB
    end
    object A_Menu_Save: TAction
      Category = 'Menu'
      Caption = 'Сохранить'
      Enabled = False
      ImageIndex = 2
      OnExecute = Menu_Save
    end
    object A_Paint_Stat: TAction
      Category = 'Paint'
      Caption = 'A_Paint_Stat'
      OnExecute = Stat_USB
    end
    object A_Scan_DevClass: TAction
      Category = 'Scan'
      Caption = 'A_Scan_DevClass'
      OnExecute = Scan_DevClass
    end
    object A_Paint_DevClass: TAction
      Category = 'Paint'
      Caption = 'A_Paint_DevClass'
      OnExecute = Paint_DevClass
    end
    object A_Scan_StorageRM: TAction
      Category = 'Scan'
      Caption = 'Scan_StorageRM'
      OnExecute = Scan_StorageRM
    end
    object A_Paint_StorageRM: TAction
      Category = 'Paint'
      Caption = 'A_Paint_StorageRM'
      OnExecute = Paint_StorageRM
    end
    object A_Scan_Setupapi: TAction
      Category = 'Scan'
      Caption = 'A_Scan_Setupapi'
      OnExecute = Scan_Setupapi
    end
  end
  object Img_48x48: TImageList
    ColorDepth = cd32Bit
    DrawingStyle = dsTransparent
    Height = 48
    Width = 48
    Left = 40
    Top = 112
    Bitmap = { Бинарные Данные (сохраните файл на диск, чтобы увидеть это) }
  end
  object Img_32x32: TImageList
    ColorDepth = cd32Bit
    DrawingStyle = dsTransparent
    Height = 32
    Width = 32
    Left = 32
    Top = 64
    Bitmap = { Бинарные Данные (сохраните файл на диск, чтобы увидеть это) }
  end
  object ImageList1: TImageList
    Left = 48
    Top = 168
    Bitmap = { Бинарные Данные (сохраните файл на диск, чтобы увидеть это) }
  end
  object SaveDialog: TSaveDialog
    DefaultExt = 'xml'
    Filter = 
      '*.xml (XML формат)|*.xml|*.sreg (файлы сканера реестра Windows)|' +
      '*.sreg'
    Options = [ofOverwritePrompt, ofHideReadOnly, ofExtensionDifferent, ofEnableSizing]
    Title = 'Сохранить  результаты сканирования...'
    Left = 512
  end
  object AdvPopupMenu: TAdvPopupMenu
    OnPopup = AdvPopupMenuPopup
    Version = '2.5.3.3'
    Left = 136
    Top = 72
    object N1: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Добавить в базу'
      OnClick = N1Click
    end
  end
  object OpenDialog: TOpenDialog
    Filter = '*.sreg (файлы сканера реестра Windows)|*.sreg'
    Left = 352
  end
  object XMLDocument1: TXMLDocument
    Active = True
    Left = 296
    Top = 8
    DOMVendorDesc = 'MSXML'
  end
end
```

Comment: Delphi?

Comment: DFM-описание формы если быть точным. Никаких путей, по которым "она смотрит историю USB устройств" (что бы это ни значило) вы тут не увидите - это не исходный код программы.

Answer (score 9):

Это код на Delphi. Но это лишь описание внешнего вида формы, кода, отвечающего за какие-либо действия здесь нет. Restorator - это не декомпилятор, а только редактор ресурсов программ, к которым в том числе относятся формы. Получить исходный код из exe'шника в большинстве случаев невозможно, максимум, что вы сможете добиться - это дизасемблированный листинг. Но, так как вы

> чайник, причем полный

вам это совершенно не поможет. А желающих копаться в ассемблерном коде не то чтобы много, так что я бы посоветовал вам забить.

Answer (score 3):

Это слова на английском языке, написанные на латинице!
А если серьезно это никакой не язык программирования, и здесь Вы точно не найдете никакого участка который хранит историю USB. 
Это обычный файл разметки интерфейса, в данном случае файл с расширением(на 99%) .dfm, который использовался в IDE Borland Delphi или С++ Builder! Для того чтобы разобраться в работе самой программы ищите файлы с расширением .pas или .cpp, а может даже оба! Многие серьезные ПО комбинировали и то и другое!

Comment: Пока я писал, кто то уже научил товарища!

Comment: а посоветуйте программку пожалуйста

Comment: >а посоветуйте программку пожалуйста

программку для чего? Для того, чтобы она могла прочитать паскалевский или ассемблерный код и рассказать вам, что он делает? Скайнет разве что. Но он с людьми вроде не очень дружит

Comment: @DreamChild а его разве не ликвидировали?

Comment: @vanyamelikov тогда все еще печальнее